# hydro and indigo in parallel

Tags: ros-hydro, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

At present i'm having Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS indigo on it. Can i run ROS hydro at the same time. If yes, can anyone please tell me how to do it?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208127/hydro-and-indigo-in-parallel./) by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2015-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hydro was not officially released for Trusty meaning there are no debs, but you may be able to install it from source following the [source install instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on 2015-05-01**:
Thanks, it worked. :)